# Servlet send redirect to welcome page?

Tags: java, servlets

How can I force a Servlet redirect to the welcome page without having to specify the exact path? Like just altering the path to the most upper one:

```
response.sendRedirect("/");
```

Which does obviously not work.

Comment: Do not forget the context path!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath() + "/"));
```

The call to encodeRedirectURL is necessary if you want to support session tracking for browsers with cookie support disabled (i.e. using URL rewriting).

Comment: Why the trailing `/`?.

Comment: Because that's where the OP wants to redirect.

Comment: I think that the OP placed the `/` in his sample code as part of his attempt to accomplish to solve his problem, but `response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath()));` should be enough and cleaner, don't you think?.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Michael-O above, following solution:

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
```